# How to discard uncommitted changes in SourceTree?

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to the Git environment, and I'm using BitBucket with SourceTree on Mac. All I want to do now is to discard the changes since last commit. How should I do this? I haven't found anything like "discard changes", and directly pulling from the last commit doesn't seem to work. Solutions done with either the GUI or command line will be good.

Comment: you mean you want to undo the last commit? or leave it and checkout the previous commit for some testing reasons for example ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I guess the answer is neither. Since the last commit, I have made some changes that I want to discard. I want my last commit back.

Comment: so you have uncommited changes that you want to revert ?

Comment: None of the answers here helped me remove the annoying 'Uncommitted changes' entry at the top of my Sourcetree. And there were too many unstaged files to Discard one by one. The answer here worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommited-changes

Comment: I was confused between context menu options when right-clicking item in Unstaged Files list; `Discard` (Shift+Ctrl+R) and `Remove` (Ctrl+Del) I guess `Discard` will revert the changes like `git reset --hard` and `Remove` will delete the file and stage that deletion.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I like to use

```
git stash
```

This stores all uncommitted changes in the [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash). If you want to discard these changes later just `git stash drop` (or `git stash pop` to restore them).

Though this is technically not the "proper" way to discard changes (as other answers and comments have pointed out).

**SourceTree**: On the top bar click on icon 'Stash', type its name and create. Then in left vertical menu you can "show" all Stash and delete in right-click menu. There is probably no other way in ST to discard all files at once.

Comment: well if you want to just discard every thing it's even easier to just do `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: @cocoanut I think my answer "wrong" because this is an abuse of the `stash` function. Mohammad's answer is the proper way to discard all changes.

Comment: Yes, and also because I couldn't see where's the shortcut.

Comment: I do like this method as it gives you one last chance to restore your changes if you change your mind. I rarely `reset --hard`, but I often stash my changes to start fresh and later drop the stash if I decide I don't need it.

Comment: This method did not delete new unversioned files. Roberto's method of using reset and clean worked better in that case.

Comment: @GabrielJensen git is not _supposed_ to care about unversioned files in most cases. `clean` is one of the few exceptions.

Comment: you can use `git stash --include-untracked` to include new, untracked files in the stash

Comment: If you by some reason want to abandon all changes made to a file in your working directory or it has been accidently deleted.

If the file has changes has been renamed or deleted it will show up in the 'Unstaged Files' list in SourceTree. If it has been deleted or renamed it will show up with a minus sign.

To instantly restore the file to the last synced state, right click the file in the SourceTree unstaged list and select 'Discard'.

Any changes should now be gone and if file was accidently deleted it should be back.

Answer (score 154):

On **SourceTree** for **Mac**, right click the files you want to discard (in the *Files in the working tree* list), and choose ***Reset***.

On **SourceTree** for **Windows**, right click the files you want to discard (in the *Working Copy Changes* list), and choose ***Discard***.

On **git**, you'd simply do:

`git reset --hard` to discard changes made to versioned files;

`git clean -xdf` to erase new (*untracked*) files, including ignored ones (the `x` option). `d` is to also remove untracked directories and `f` to force.

Comment: You can also right click on the entire "Working Copy" in the left panel (or press Cmd+Shift+R) ;-)

Comment: Amazing that the same command has a different name for Mac and Windows.  As if Git GUI (compared to command line) wasn't confusing enough already.

Comment: Thanks! I Think this should be Voted as the Right Answer ;-)

Comment: @NSTJ: Agreed ... it pretty well shakes one's confidence in the possibility of assigning a consistent definition to terms like "reset" and "discard" in regard to git tools. I.e. a definition that you can expect to be widely agreed upon.

Comment: Be very careful about `git clean -xdf` command.  It can do a lot of damage.

Answer (score 17):

*Follow steps to discard multiple uncommited changes in Sourcetree.*

> New version of Sourcetree does not have -*Reset Button*- as mentioned previous answer. Thus, please follow these 5 steps for solution.

1. Right click "***File status***" and click "***Reset...***".

[image]

> 

2. **Select files**. *If you want, you can select all of them like the below image.*

[image]

> 

3. Click "***Reset All***".

[image]

> 

4. Again click "***Reset All***".

[image]

> 

5. Click "***Reset***".

[image]

> 

***Welldone..! No more 302 files to discard.***

[image]

Comment: Thanks worked for latest source tree versions , 2021

Answer (score 9):

On the unstaged file, click on the three dots on the right side. Once you click it, a popover menu will appear where you can then `Discard file`.

Comment: This is fine when it's only a few files, but what happens when there's a lot of files?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I just noticed that my question was already answered in the question title.

To unstage files use

```
git reset HEAD /file/name
```

And to undo the changes to a file

```
git checkout -- /file/name
```

If you have a batch of files inside a folder you can undo the whole folder

```
git checkout -- /folder/name
```

Note that all these commands are already displayed when you `git status`

Here I created a dummy repo and listed all 3 possibilities

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   test
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   test2
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       test3
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok so in Windows sourcetree that is simple, on macOS I looked as well for a while..

**Click Command + Shift + R while in source tree**  a hidden popup will be shown that will let you discard individual files OR ALL! Why is this hidden? We will never know.. but it works!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From sourcetree gui click on working directoy, right-click the file(s) that you want to discard, then click on Discard

Answer (score 1):

Do as follow,

- Click on `commit`
- Select all by pressing `CMD+A` that you want to `delete or discard`
- `Right click` on the selected uncommitted files that you want to delete
- Select `Remove` from the drop-down list

Comment: This removes the existing files, not discard the changes!

Answer (score 0):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

For me, there was only one option to discard all.

[image]