# GitHub with SourceThree ERROR in Push

Tags: java, github, sourcetree

[image]

[image]

Now I Create a branch and didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Creating a branch would not be enough to get past the error message "`The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge`"

You need, with SourceTree, to either:

- [stash your untracked file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/stash-a-file-with-sourcetree-785332122.html) (if you want to keep that untracked file)

[image]

- or [clean (ie delete) it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21873813/6309): it is called **discard**

> right click the files you want to discard (in the Working Copy Changes list), and choose Discard.