# SourceTree delete uncommitted new files

Tags: git

When a merge fails I get a lot of new untracked files, if I want to redo the commit it fails because the files would be overwritten.

In Git Extension I can simply delete the all files, but I cannot find how to do it with SourceTree

If I try to to 'git clean -fd' ([How to discard uncommitted changes in SourceTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234523/how-to-discard-uncommitted-changes-in-sourcetree)) than it deletes files under ignored directory (`.vagrant/` even though I have `.vagrant/*` in my gitignore ).

Note: I know that I can delete the files 1-by-1 but I want to delete all new uncommitted files that are not in gitignore

Please help

Comment: Are the uncommitted files modified files already in the repo or new untracked files?

Comment: new untracked files