# How to revert changes to an uncommited file

Tags: git, rubymine, revert

I had a file the way I wanted it and committed it, then changes were made to it and not committed.

There is no remote associated with the repo.

How do I revert the most recent changes that were not committed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git undo all uncommitted changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

or

```
git checkout -- <file path + name>
```

> **`git-reset`**
>   Reset current HEAD to the specified state

[image]

Comment: Thanks! cool visualization. I will look into the diff between `reset head --hard` and `checkout -- <file path + name>` .  Do I need to type the actual `<` and `>` ?