# How to change current repo to a new one while conserving all previous commits

Tags: git

#### My current state:

- Created and commited a JS development environment - call it Master A.
- Continued to write new code on Master A, yet didn't commit any of the new code yet.

#### Expected state:

- I would like my initial commit to Master B to include all the new and uncommitted written code from Master A + Include all commits of Master A.
- I would like to have Master A available and re-usable to use it as a boilerplate for future JS environment projects.

I am looking for a stenciled workflow solution, not a one time solution for this issue.

Not looking to create new branches on Master A as solution, please.
I would like to keep Master A organic for others to pull and benefit with no clutter/branches.

Thanks,

Buddy

Comment: are you looking for git config remote.origin.url?

Comment: This master B is in same repository or other?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki - Master B is not yet created, as it's my question here :) it should be a fresh repo that would carry all the commits of Master A + newly written and uncommited code from A

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh - sounds interesting, please continue with this line, I thought about it too yet couldn't figure if I am totally seperating B and A totally (which I am looking for)

Comment: The comment by @UdayrajDeshmukh seems perfect but you won't be able to catch uncommitted code from master A. Unless you commit the code from master A it can not be moved to a new repo

Comment: @ArpitSolanki - that's why I asked him to continue with that, since that line alone will 'contaminate' Master A with unnecessary commits.

Comment: cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your scenario I created two repositories `testgitA` and `testgitB`.
`testgitA` contains some commits as well as some new uncommitted changes, whereas `testgitB` is empty.

Now, for "B to include all the new and uncommitted written code from A + Include all commits of A", I'd follow these steps:

1. Duplicate the folder `testgitA` into a new folder `testgitB`.

   `cp -R testgitA/ testgitB/`

   Note: This is to catch the uncommitted code.
2. Go into `testgitB` and change the url of remote origin to new one.

   `cd testgitB/
   git config remote.origin.url "https://github.com/Udayraj123/testgitB"`
3. Now you commit your changes into `testgitB`, where `testgitA` remains unaffected.

   `git add . && git commit -m "into testgitB"`
4. If you want to discard uncommitted changes in the boilerplate repo, use the following command.

   `cd ../testgitA
    git add .
    git stash`

Ref: [More ways to discard uncommitted changes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes)