# I made changes to a lot of files but didn't yet do a commit. How can I back out of all the changes?

Tags: git, github

Here's what gitstatus shows me:

```
MacBook:Ja.git alan$ git status
On branch alan-1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/alan-1'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Ja/Views/DictionaryTab/DictionaryTabPage.xaml.cs
    modified:   Ja/Views/HomeTab/HomeTabPage.xaml
    modified:   Ja/Views/HomeTab/HomeTabPage.xaml.cs
    modified:   Ja/Views/MainPage.xaml.cs
    modified:   Ja/Views/SettingsTab/SettingsTabPage.xaml.cs
    modified:   Ja/Views/SettingsTab/Subscriptions.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
MacBook:Ja.git alan$
```

Would appreciate advice as it's important I just go back to the point before I changed these files.

Comment: git reset --hard or git stash (in case you need to preserve those modified files)

Comment: What is wrong with the suggested `git checkout -- <file>...` ?

Comment: git checkout -- <file> would write local changes to a file.

Comment: Nope, that would revert changes made in the file, that are not yet commited. As it says in the console output.

Comment: You want to "discard changes in working directory"?

Comment: Sounds like git reset --hard might be the best solution here.

Comment: Yes, I would like to discard all my changes and make it look like it looked an hour ago before I started changing the files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git undo all uncommitted or unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+local+changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git checkout --name_of_file allows you to recover original versioon

Comment: Is there a way to do that for all of the files at once or maybe better can I revert to the last commit locally?