# How to delete all my unstaged changes with a single git command?

Tags: git

I'm using git for java projects and I did changes in many classes and I didn't do git add, git commit and push. And now I want to delete all my changes. How can I do that? Is there a git command because I don't want to delete all the code manually? Thank you!

Comment: When you type `git status`, it will hint at using `git restore ... `. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Try `git restore .` or `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
git checkout .
```

or

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

or (assuming you're on branch master)

```
git reset --hard master
```

Answer (score 1):

After

git stash
git stash drop

all files added to "staged"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use git command, so look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes).

Another suggestion is you can use program that make you easy to use git, like [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), [VSCODE version control](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol). That tools have functions that you can make it easy to manage your git project.