# How to go back to initial state of a branch with git in eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, undo

I recovered code in Eclipse via git clone function.
I worked with a branch of the project and made some modifications (~20), now i realize I want to back to the initial state ( the moment I recovered it) , i didn't perform any commit , but windows of stages and unstaged changes list present lot a files.

How can I go back to the first time I open this branch using Eclipse functionnality ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git undo all uncommitted or unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i would like to do it using Eclipse functionnality

Comment: In the _History_ view right-click the last commit and do _Reset > Hard_ or in the _Package/Project Explorer_ right-click projects/folder/file and choose _Replace With > HEAD Revision_ or in the _Git Staging_ view right-click and _Replace With HEAD Revision_ or ...

Comment: thanks howlger, add your message as response this way i can validate it as solution