# Pycharm "keeping changes" when checking out from one branch to another?

Tags: git, pycharm

I am learning to use git from command line, I have been using it from Pycharm GUI.

I am working on `my_project` directory with pycharm, on branch `my_branch`.

Now, I want to bring some new feature to my code, and I want to do it in another branch, so that in case I spoil something I can abort the new feature by simply deleting the new branch.

To create and switch to the new branch I have run `git checkout -b my_branch_2`, started to do some changes (committed none), then I want to go back to `my_branch`, so I run `git checkout my_branch`.

At this point, as Pycharm GUI usually does when one tryes to checkout from a branch with uncommitted changes to another branch, I expected git to ask me if I want to commit the changes or to checkout and discard the changes to `my_branch_2` and to switch to `my_branch` code (Pycharm executes this latter option when the user select the button "force checkout").

Instead, it switches back to `my_branch` without asking anything and carrying the changes I made to `my_branch_2`, so that eventually wrong code is brought to my stable branch !

Why does it happen?

Am I using wrong the command `git checkout`?

Which git commands do I have to run to replicate the behavior of Pycharm when I choose the "Force checkout" option from its GUI?

Comment: Modified files belong to the working tree but not to any branch. To add them to a branch do checkout and commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed

If you don't want those to carry over, either [reset, stash or clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes) them.

So, the equivalent of "Pycharm's forced checkout" on command line (which will delete all uncommitted local changes and switch from the current branch to `my_branch`) is

```
git checkout . && git checkout my_branch
```

and this has to be run in root directory.