# how do i override local files with current version on github?

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-3.2, local, scaffolding

I generated and destroyed a scaffold, generated a new scaffold, which resulted in a huge mess, such as the CSS (nav fonts are not correct, buttons have a hover yet nothing was specified in the file originally).  The "description" field did not appear with the new scaffold and more.  I have gone through the new scaffold files and have spent hours to only prefer to have the current version I pushed override the local files and start over from that point.

Is there a way to download the last version i pushed to github to override the current local files and start from there?  I have not committed any of the current changes.

Comment: It looks like this question has been asked before.  Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999259/git-how-to-perform-the-tfs-equivalent-of-undo-pending-changes

Answer (score -1):

you can "undo" your changes in git very easily with the reset command.

`git reset HEAD --hard`

will force remove all your changes to the state they were in the HEAD revision.